# Recursion in C for hashcode

Tags: c, recursion, hash

I'm trying to make a hashcode function.

However, I get a random number not equal to the example, and I can't determine why (5 is the max length, so no need for dynamic memory allocation)

Comment: Just fyi, there should be no need for dynamic allocation whether the length is 5 or not. A setup to a recursive forward function will do this for any arbitrary length, and not require string allocations  nor copies. [**See it live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8072c4f996eabb16)

Comment: Why did you decide to use recursion here? You would be better served to use a simple loop.

Comment: @StilesCrisis not sure if you're asking me or the OP, but if me, because it is apparently a requirement of the OP's task (I only assume its an academic exercise). Were it I (and apparently you) a simple loop would be the order of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `strncpy` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/):

> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if
>   source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not
>   be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would
>   overflow).

so you want to do:

```
strncpy(new, str, l - 1);
new[l - 1] = 0;
```

But you can also avoid creating new strings using a helper function:

```
unsigned long hash_helper(const char* str, int len){
    if (len == 0) return 0;
    return hash_helper(str, len - 1) * 65599 + str[len - 1]; 
}

unsigned long hash(const char* str){
    return hash_helper(str, strlen(str));
}
```

Comment: @Dad are you *sure* you're compiling on a machine with a 64bit unsigned long? I ask because.. well. [**ideone.com sample**](http://ideone.com/4LVRLT) clearly has 32bit `unsigned long`, whereas this [**coliru sample**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8072c4f996eabb16) with the same code is using a 64bit implementation. If you're getting the former rather than the latter, perhaps check your compiler target.

Comment: @Dad, if your `long`s are not wide enough, try `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long`.

Comment: the method needs to fit specified prototypes so I wouldnt be able to change it to long long, I'm so confused on what to do

Comment: @Dad, if unsigned long can't store the desired result on your architecture then there is only a single option: assume a 64bit architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but feel recursion is a weird way to code it (in C — in LISP, it would be fine).  In this code, `hash1()` is a simple iterative version of the hash function; `hash2()` follows the recursive specification, using `hash3()` as a helper function (it needs the length):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned long hash1(const char *str)
{
    unsigned long h = 0;
    while (*str != '\0')
        h = h * 65599 + *str++;
    return h;
}

static unsigned long hash3(const char *str, size_t len)
{
    unsigned long h = 0;
    if (len > 0)
        h = hash3(str, len - 1) * 65599 + str[len-1];
    return h;
}

static unsigned long hash2(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    return hash3(str, len);
}

static int test_hash(const char *str)
{
    unsigned long h1 = hash1(str);
    unsigned long h2 = hash2(str);
    int rc = 0;
    const char *pass_fail = "PASS";
    if (h1 != h2)
    {
        rc = 1;
        pass_fail = "FAIL";
    }
    printf("h1 = %lu, h2 = %lu: %s (%s)\n", h1, h2, pass_fail, str);
    return rc;
}

int main(void)
{
    static const char *data[] =
    {
        "ice", "man", "cometh", "the iceman cometh",
    };
    int failures = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]); i++)
        failures += test_hash(data[i]);
    printf("%s\n", (failures == 0) ? "== PASS ==" : "!! FAIL !!");
    return !(failures == 0);
}
```

Sample output (on a 64-bit platform, GCC 4.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.5):

```
h1 = 451845518507, h2 = 451845518507: PASS (ice)
h1 = 469058302522, h2 = 469058302522: PASS (man)
h1 = 8177059914254772472, h2 = 8177059914254772472: PASS (cometh)
h1 = 2988038870251942490, h2 = 2988038870251942490: PASS (the iceman cometh)
== PASS ==
```

Note that the code for `ice` matches the example.  When compiled as a 32-bit program, the output is:

```
h1 = 873952427, h2 = 873952427: PASS (ice)
h1 = 906867258, h2 = 906867258: PASS (man)
h1 = 138275064, h2 = 138275064: PASS (cometh)
h1 = 1819095642, h2 = 1819095642: PASS (the iceman cometh)
== PASS ==
```